# How to pass a NSMutableArray to another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

Following code fragment is part of the `prepareForSegue` method.  In that I want to pass `self.mutaArr` (MutableArray) to `SecViewController` (Which is a `UIViewController`).

This is not getting passed because of the following line:

`[navController setViewControllers:@[dvc] animated: NO ];`

If I pass `s` I end up getting a black screen. Therefore, how do i sort this?

Please note that I am using `SWRevealViewController` as well.

```
if ([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]]) {

    SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;    
    swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"gosegue"]) {

        UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        SecViewController *s = [[SecViewController alloc] init];
        s.myMutableArr= self.mutaArr;
        [navController setViewControllers:@[dvc] animated: NO ];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
....
```

Comment: What is `svc` during the segue? And what is `s` supposed to be as you are switching to view `dvc`

Comment: Why do you use `setViewControllers` in `prepareForSegue` in the first place? Also, you never use the `s` variable, so it comes as no surprise, that `self.mutaArr` is not passed anywhere.

Comment: one point, **if indeed you're going to put it in a singleton**, of course simply put it in the AppDelegate.  Just add a property to AppDelegate.h, as easy as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of trouble from the code you provided:

1. You have to define a property in the destination view controller of your segue that can hold your array and set it in the `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method of your source view controller. That ensures you set your data structure (i.e. your array) **before** the transition. You can retrieve the destination view controller of your segue by doing

   ```
   UIViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];
   SecViewController *destination = (SecViewController *)viewController;
   destination.arrayHoldingProperty = self.myArray;
   ```

   Here it's assumed you have defined the `arrayHoldingProperty` in your `SecViewController` class.
2. Having done the first step, you can then perform the segue from wherever you want using the `performSegueWithIdentifier:@"whatever" sender:nil` method.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any role of your variable `s` except setting a mutable array, have you pushed this controller anywhere? Perhaps:

```
SecViewController *s = [[SecViewController alloc] init];
s.myMutableArr= self.mutaArr;

navController setViewControllers:@[s] animated: NO ];  // Notice `s` replaced `dvc`
```

IMHO, the best to pass a value from one controller/view to other controller/view is to use session (i.e., Singleton class). Set value in a session inside `swSegue.performBlock` block and get value in `viewDidLoad` of `SecViewController`.

**EDIT**:

Look at [this tutorial](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) for singleton implementation. In the second example `someProperty` can be `your array`.

For getting black screen,i just noticed that you didn't reflect the `navController` to `self.revealViewController`.

Perhaps using this:

```
- (void)pushFrontViewController:(UIViewController *)frontViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

to push `navController` on `self.revealViewController` may fix black screen issue.

**EDIT:**

Try like this:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"gosegue"]) {

    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    SecViewController *s = [[SecViewController alloc] init];
    s.myMutableArr= self.mutaArr;
    [navController setViewControllers:@[s] animated: NO ];
    [self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:s animated: YES];
    // OR
    //[self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:navController animated: YES];
    ....
```

Comment: When i set `@['s']` i get a blank screen. Can you show me a detail example on how to set to a singleton class

Comment: Can you show me how to pass it too. I am a bit confused.

Comment: I get this error `No visible @interface for 'SWRevealViewController' declares the selector 'pushFrontViewController:animated:'`

Comment: Are you using this control: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController See this function is list in the section `Basic API Description`. May be you have to update this API ?

Answer (score 0):

You are making another instance of SecViewController class

```
  SecViewController *s = [[SecViewController alloc] init];
```

Don't Use this instead of use this:

```
 SecViewController *s = (SecViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecViewController"];
 s.myMutableArr= self.mutaArr;
```